# Loop join or recursive in sql to get the max level?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, laravel

I have a database table name "category" and has attributes of:

- id
- parent_id
- code
- name

**Sample Data:**

```
[1][null][0][category 1]
[2][null][1][category 2]
[3][null][2][category 3]
[4][null][3][category 4]
[5][3][4][category 5]
[6][null][5][category 6]
[7][5][0][category 7]
[8][null][1][category 8]
[9][7][2][category 9]
[10][null][3][category 10]
[11][null][4][category 11]
[12][null][5][category 12]
```

Category table is like a tree or nodes. It can have different level.

For the example data, the category 9 is the child of category 7. And the category 7 is the child of category 5. And the category 5 is the child of category 3.

So you can imagine this category like tree or node.

Category 3 > Category 5 > Category 7 > Category 9

So category 9 is the level 4.

So my question, how to get the maximum level so the expected result is 4.

Comment: Have you made any attempts so far?  If it is a small table, it may be better to read it all into memory and work it out from there rather than multiple SQL calls.

Comment: Actually this is only a part on my task. I only need to get the maximum level of the recursion then I will loop the category table depends on the level.

So if I get a result of 4

Then I will loop 4 times this category table to get the parent category id

Comment: If you need to read the data again, then I would have thought having the data in memory would be better.  Why keep on going back to the database and the overhead of more SQL statements?

Comment: Then for example I have a 100 category and some of them may have a different level. So you mean I'll loop it in the backend side then avoid this to sql?

Comment: recursive CTE is the best for these type of problems

Comment: @Atk how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want count for category 3

```
create table #temp
(
id int,
parent_id int,
code int,
name varchar(20)
)

insert into #temp values(1,null,0,'category 1')
insert into #temp values(2,null,1,'category 2')
insert into #temp values(3,null,2,'category 3')
insert into #temp values(4,null,3,'category 4')
insert into #temp values(5,3,4,'category 5')
insert into #temp values(6,null,5,'category 6')
insert into #temp values(7,5,0,'category 7')
insert into #temp values(8,null,1,'category 8')
insert into #temp values(9,7,2,'category 9')
insert into #temp values(10,null,3,'category 10')
insert into #temp values(11,null,4,'category 11')
insert into #temp values(12,null,5,'category 12')



;WITH items AS (
    SELECT id,name,parent_id
    FROM #temp 
    WHERE parent_id is null and id=3
    UNION ALL

    SELECT i.id,i.name,i.parent_id
    FROM #temp i
    INNER JOIN items itms ON itms.id = i.parent_id
)
SELECT count(*) FROM items
```